# How can I batch get-network-sm-devices in Meraki SM API v1?

Tags: meraki-api

I am converting my call to Meraki API v0 to v1 because v0 has sunset.

I am trying to retrieve all devices in batches for SM devices. Specifically this API call: https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/api/get-network-sm-devices/

In the v0 version of this API, params and the response looked like the following.

Params 1

```
batchSize: 3
```

Request 1

```
{
  "batchToken": "123abc",
  "devices": [{"id": "device1"}, {"id": "device2"}, {"id": "device3"}]
}
```

I see a batchToken, so there are more devices to retrieve.

Params 2

```
batchToken: "123abc"
```

Request 2 Response

```
{
  "batchToken": "456def",
  "devices": [{"id": "device4"}, {"id": "device5"}, {"id": "device6"}
}
```

Awesome! And there are still more to retrieve so now I use the new batchToken until there isn't one. This was in v0 though.

In API v1, the same request looks like this.

Params 1

```
perPage: 3
```

Request 1 Response

```
[{"id": "device1"}, {"id": "device2"}, {"id": "device3"}]
```

There is no batchToken. If it was documented, I didn't understand how to implement the same behavior as in v0. If it's not possible to do this, which API call would I need to see how many devices there are total in this network so I could break my requests up on my own?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `get-network-sm-devices` endpoint API for V1 we can use the following approach:

1. Instead of "`batchSize`" query parameter we use "`perPage`". It's the number of entries per page returned. The acceptable range is 3 - 1000. Default value - 1000.
2. If there are 3000 devices, for instance, we can use "`startingAfter`" query parameter with the default value for "`perPage`". It can be a timestamp or device ID, but it's not limited to those.

Be careful, "`startingAfter`" parameter does not support "`None`" value. It will return an error. So, for your case, you can create a variable that will contain the last device ID from the first request and pass it as a query parameter to the next one.

Have a nice day!